# What eigenstates of the Fock operator gives the Hartree Fock ground state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-chemistry, ground-state

In the Hartree Fock method with $N$ electrons, the Fock operator is a one-electron operator defined by
$$f := h + \sum_{n=1}^N J_n - K_n,$$
where $h = -\frac{1}{2} \nabla^2 + V_{el-nu}$ is the one-electron operator in the Hamiltonian $H$, $\sum_{n=1}^N J_n$ is the Coulomb operator and $\sum_{n=1}^N K_n$ is the exchange operator. The last two dependend on a set of $N$ orthonormal spin orbitals. The Hartree Fock ground state is then a slater determinant $\psi$ of $N$ orthonormal eigenstates $\{\psi_1,\dots,\psi_N\}$ of $f$ where the Coulomb and the exchange operator are constructed from those eigenstates.
$$f\psi_k = \varepsilon_k\psi_k \qquad \forall k=1,\dots,N.$$

Question: What eigenstates of $f$ gives the lowest energy $E := \langle\psi, H\psi\rangle$? According to textbooks one should pick the eigenstates with the lowest eigenvalues $\{\varepsilon_k\}$. But $E \neq \sum_{n=1}^N \varepsilon_n$. We have
$$E = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\varepsilon_n + \langle\psi_n, h\psi_n\rangle}{2}.$$
Shouldn't one look for the eigenstates $\psi_k$ with the smallest $\varepsilon_k + \langle\psi_k, h\psi_k\rangle$ instead? Or is it so that
$$\begin{align*}
\varepsilon_k = \varepsilon_l \qquad&\Longrightarrow\qquad \langle\psi_k, h\psi_k\rangle = \langle\psi_l, h\psi_l\rangle \\
\varepsilon_k < \varepsilon_l \qquad&\Longrightarrow\qquad \langle\psi_k, h\psi_k\rangle < \langle\psi_l, h\psi_l\rangle \ ?
\end{align*}$$